# Angular - Multiple div element slideshow

Tags: html, css, angular, carousel

I'm trying to create a web site in which a lot of div are being displayed with a *ngFor loop. Here is the code

```
<div class="container-fluid" style="background-color: #151923; background-size: cover; padding: 0; min-height: 100vh;">
<h3 style="text-align: center; color: floralwhite">Clients Aperçus !</h3>
<div class="row" style="margin-top: 60px;">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-3" *ngFor="let client of getClients()" style="text-align: center;" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalClientEdit" data-dismiss="modal" (click)="onDisplayClient(client)">
            <img *ngIf="client.recognize === true" class="img-circle avatarBlue" src={{client.pict}} style="width: 250px; height: 250px;" alt="Img">
            <img *ngIf="client.recognize === false" class="img-circle avatarRed" src={{client.pict}} style="width: 250px; height: 250px;" alt="Img">
            <p>{{client.firstName}} {{client.lastName}}</p>
            <img *ngIf="client.language.indexOf('FR') > -1" src="../../assets/blank.gif" class="flag flag-fr"/>
            <img *ngIf="client.language.indexOf('GB') > -1" src="../../assets/blank.gif" class="flag flag-gb"/>
            <img *ngIf="client.language.indexOf('CN') > -1" src="../../assets/blank.gif" class="flag flag-cn"/>
            <img *ngIf="client.language.indexOf('JP') > -1" src="../../assets/blank.gif" class="flag flag-jp"/>
            <img *ngIf="client.language.indexOf('DE') > -1" src="../../assets/blank.gif" class="flag flag-de"/>
            <img *ngIf="client.language.indexOf('IT') > -1" src="../../assets/blank.gif" class="flag flag-it"/>
            <img *ngIf="client.language.indexOf('ES') > -1" src="../../assets/blank.gif" class="flag flag-es"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Since each div has the "col-xs-3" class, only 4 divs are being displayed in one row. If I have 5 elements to display, the fifth one will be below the first row. What I'd like to implement is a "carousel-like" behavior. For instance, if my list has 8 elements, only the first fourth will be displayed and a "right arrow" will be able to show the next fourth. I have no idea how I could achieve that. I've been looking at some post regarding multiple-element inside carousel but I'm not sure this is the right thing to do.

Comment: Use a carousel plugin like http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

Comment: Thanks a lot! I've never used JQuery though, I have no idea how to implement that in my code. I'll give it a try !